# Find on AIX with output to file

Tags: find, aix

```
find /apps/dynalife/clients/. ! -path "train" -type f -mtime +90 ! \( -name "*.p" -o -name "*.i" -o -name "*.w" -o -name "*.cls" -o -name "*.inf" -o -name "*.bat" \) -exec {} \; > /apps/dynalife/util/delFile.lst
```

I am trying to find all files older than 90 days in `/apps/dynalife/clients/` and all subfolders. But I exclude the subfolder `/apps/dynalife/clients/train/` and I also want to exclude all files with extensions ending in one of a few values `p` / `i` / `w` / `cls` / `inf` / `bat`

The script is just producing an empty file.

The idea is to have a file I can check and then use as input for the `rm` command to remove all the files found.

Updated Find:

```
find /apps/dynalife/clients/ ! -path "*/mapwrk/*" -type f -mtime +90 ! \( -name "*.p" -o -name "*.i" -o -name "*.w" -o -name "*.cls" -o -name "*.inf" -o -name "*.bat" -o -name "*.ini" -o -name "*.pf" -o -name "*.wob" -o -name "*CIM900*" \) -print > /apps/dynalife/util/delFile.lst
```

Updated Delete:

```
xargs rm < /apps/dynalife/util/delFile.lst
```

Answer (score 2):

You only pass the filename to `-exec` so that does not do anything. You need to use `-print0` so you also can handle filenames with newlines and other special characters, so do something like:

```
find /apps/dynalife/clients/. ! -path "train" -type f -mtime +90 ! \( -name "*.p" -o -name "*.i" -o -name "*.w" -o -name "*.cls" -o -name "*.inf" -o -name "*.bat" \) -print0 > /apps/dynalife/util/delFile.lst
```

That will give you a list that you can feed into `rm` using:

```
cat /apps/dynalife/util/delFile.lst | xargs -0 rm
```

If your find does not support -print0 and your filenames do not contain newlines (but spaces) you can use `-print`:

```
find /apps/dynalife/clients/. ! -path "train" -type f -mtime +90 ! \( -name "*.p" -o -name "*.i" -o -name "*.w" -o -name "*.cls" -o -name "*.inf" -o -name "*.bat" \) -print > /apps/dynalife/util/delFile.lst
```

and:

```
cat /apps/dynalife/util/delFile.lst | xargs rm
```

Comment: NOT WORKING. find: 0652-017 -print0 is not a valid option

Comment: `-print0` is a GNUism (IIRC); you'll have to use `-print` instead, which will break on filenames containing newlines. `-print0` seperates the files with nullbyte, which is the only character that cannot appear in a file path according to the standards and so is bulletproof; `-print` seperates with newlines, and so will break if your filenames contain newlines (which I've never seen outside of files created specifically to test scripts).

Comment: @evilsoup thank you, give me same results as the echo option. So all working

Comment: You've got some UUOCs, the argument to `-path` has to be a path, not just a name, for `xargs`, you need to escape space, tab, single quote, double quote and backslash characters in addition to newlines.

Comment: cat /apps/dynalife/util/delFile.lst | xargs -0 rm does not work   --> xargs rm < /apps/dynalife/util/delFile.lst worked

Comment: @StephaneChazelas nope it does not have to be complete path can use wild cards I use */train/* as the folder name can be in any of the subfolders.

Comment: @AquaAlex, yes and the wildcard matches the complete path. `-path train` will never match `-path '*/train'` is the same as `-name train`.

Answer (score 2):

The argument to `-path` is to match the path. `-path trains` would never match anything.

```
find /apps/dynalife/clients ! -path '/apps/dynalife/clients/trains/*' \
  -type f -mtime +90 ! \( -name "*.p" -o -name "*.i" -o -name "*.w" \
  -o -name "*.cls" -o -name "*.inf" -o -name "*.bat" \
  \)  > /apps/dynalife/util/delFile.lst
```

Though, if you don't intend to find any file in `trains`, you might as well *prune* it to avoid descending in it:

```
find /apps/dynalife/clients -path /apps/dynalife/clients/trains -prune -o \
  -type f -mtime +90 ! \( -name "*.p" -o -name "*.i" -o -name "*.w" \
  -o -name "*.cls" -o -name "*.inf" -o -name "*.bat" \
  \) -print > /apps/dynalife/util/delFile.lst
```

Assuming none of the file names contain newline characters, you can remove them with:

```
sed 's/./\\&/g' < /apps/dynalife/util/delFile.lst | xargs rm -f
```

Here, we're escaping every character (but newline) so that they are not considered specially by `xargs`. Strictly speaking, only:

```
sed "s/[\\' \"$(printf '\t')]/\\\\&/g"
```

is needed (that is, only space, tab, backslash, single and double quotes need escaped).

Comment: actually */train/* works perfectly, especially since the path could be in any position

Comment: there is an * before and after / all files in that folder and its subfolders are skipped

Comment: @AquaAlex, yes though that would skip the files in all the folders called `train`, not just `/apps/dynalife/clients/train`, and `find` still descends into those which is why you may want to use `-prune` as an optimisation.